# Mean value therorem proof WITHOUT Rolle

Tags: real-analysis

MVT is a quasi-direct consequence of Rolle's theorem (RT), but in fact we know that  both are equivalent (RT is often said to be a particular case of MVT), and that both are equivalent to the least-upper-bound property of $\mathbb{R}$ (LUB).

The thing is that I can't find a proof of LUB $\Rightarrow$ MVT.
Can you give me some details or book/paper references, please?

Comment: [You mean like this?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle's_theorem#Proof_of_the_generalized_version)

Comment: Oh no! I'm not looking for results or generalization of Rolle's theorem but for direct proof of MVT, but thanks...

Comment: look closer it's a proof of LUB implies RT

Comment: Yes, but this is the very classical way one can find in every book: LUB--> RT--> MVT. What I can't find is LUB-->MVT-- > RT...

Comment: I am wondering the same thing , have you found the proof